# combining Rows in SQL which are in the same column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, odbc

I am trying to combine two columns into two rows. I am unbale to work it out with the PIVOT table.
My table looks like this

```
name | status | timestamp
212         50      t1
213         50      t2
212         60      t3
213         60      t4
```

what I want

```
name | starttime | stoptime
212       t1         t2
213       t3         t4
```

Comment: can you explain the logic behind this in more detail. why does 212 stops at t2 ? why does 213 starts at t3 ?

Comment: you can use aggregation, grouping by name.

Comment: Are you ***really*** still using SQL Server 2005? That's been *completely* unsupported for ~5 years; you really need to sort out your upgrade path. Many of us can't remember what that features we take for granted support (or worse, doesn't support) as we haven't touched such an old product in as many years. Not upgrading sooner will only make it harder further down the line.

Comment: Your sample data and desired output seem to be confused. And even worse it seems you are expecting some sort of order to your data here because you have start and stop. But in your data there is nothing to indicate order. Provide some meaningful sample data and help others understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the table name is TimeSheet and the table already has an ID which is auto-increment then you may use something like this:

```
SELECT TSS.Name,
   (
       SELECT TOP (1)
              TS.timestamp
       FROM TimeSheet TS
       WHERE TS.Name = TSS.Name
       ORDER BY TS.ID ASC
   ) AS Starttime,
   (
       SELECT TOP (1)
              TS.timestamp
       FROM TimeSheet TS
       WHERE TS.Name = TSS.Name
       ORDER BY TS.ID DESC
   ) AS Endtime
FROM TimeSheet TSS 
GROUP BY TSS.Name
```

Comment: I completely got you, but the status is very important. based on status, the time stamp has to be arranged,. Start time denoted status 50 and stop time denotes status 60.

Comment: Couldn't you just add status in where clause of sub queries?